# TableView Controller shows cells under status bar

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my view controller, I have an `UIImageView` with a frame of (0, 0,  and a hidden `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar` on top. The tableview has a frame of (0, 20, 320, 548) to show the imageview under the status bar whenever the tableview is shown. However, when I scroll the cells up past the search bar, the cells go over the imageview but under the status bar text.

Why is this happening when the tableview's frame starts at (0, 20)? How can I make the imageview show under the status bar when the tableview is shown, without having the cells block it?

Edit:

I started with a ViewController created in storyboard. Both the `UIImageView` and `UITableView` are subviews of the main view. The button's outlet is called searchBarLikeButton.

```
- (IBAction)searchBarLikeAction:(id)sender {

    //Hide button, show table, make searchBar the first responder. 
    self.searchBarLikeButton.hidden = YES;
    self.carTableView.hidden = NO;
    [self.searchBarByName becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: UIImageView is the subview of which object? UITableView? UIViewController? It is easier to help you if you can paste some code here.

Comment: I added some code to the question. If the button is pressed, I want to enable the user to start searching. When the user is done searching, if they scroll up, the cells go above y=20, which means they are above the imageview and out of the tableview's frame. How can I prevent this behavior?